# Make text not go beyond footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to write a very basic chat website.
When the chat log is very long (page filling or longer) the text goes beyond/under the footer. The footer, in this case, is the textarea where you write your chat message.

This is the current index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
<div id="footer">
<footer>
<form method="post" action="/api/msg" id="form">
  <textarea autofocus name="msg" id="msgfield" rows=3 cols=80></textarea>
</form>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is style.css:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* start of snippet that doesn't do anything */
msgs {
  height: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
/* end of snippet that doesn't do anything */

textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: -17;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

As you can see there is a block in style.css that should prevent the div "msgs" from reaching too far down. However, the complete block does nothing as if it didn't know what "msgs" is.
Also the whole page becomes scrollable, including the footer. The footer should stay below the scrollable area.

How can I achieve this behaviour and prevent the current one?

Comment: can you share working code which recreates the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The messages come from a SQLite3 database and the handlers are written in purescript. My jurisdiction is only the html and css files. Or did I misunderstand what you mean with "working code"? Because this is absolutely everything and it compiles. If there were more code to show you I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 'fixed' removes the element from the flow. This can work but you have to size the msgs element to make sure it doesn't go behind it. The method I use below makes the two elements directly related to each other spacially. The parent display of flex makes the two children create a column. Some rules here and there, shown below, instruct them how to take up space.

Added an overflow: auto that allows that content to scroll when too long.

CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; } // so padding and borders are included in sizes

body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

chat-box { // using custom tag
  display: flex; // magic
  flex-flow: column; // column
  height: 100vh; // better than height: 100% when full window height
}

#msgs {
  flex: 1; // makes this flex element grow to fill the space
  overflow: auto; // adds a scrollbar if too long
  padding: 1em; // for pretty
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  padding: 0.4em 0.35em 0.2em 0.35em; // for pretty
  background: #ccc; // for pretty
}

form { // removing native spacing
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<chat-box>
  <div id="msgs"></div>
  <footer>
    <form method="post" action="/api/msg" id="form">
      <textarea autofocus name="msg" id="msgfield" rows=3 cols=80></textarea>
    </form>
  </footer>
</chat-box>
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I know the original problem is solved now, but could you maybe also help me to get the page to load with the scroll bar scrolled down to the max?

Comment: JS is best for that. You have to find the scroll height then scroll to that. JQuery can animate that pretty easy.

Comment: So there would be no possibility for someone who uses a script blocker to be instantly scrolled down? That's what I was afraid of. I was looking for a pure css or html solution and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

msgs is an "id", CSS selector for that would be "#msgs".
Same for your footer > #footer

Comment: You mean exchanging 
`msgs {
  height: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}`
with
`#msgs {
  height: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}`
right? That does nothing.

Comment: Ok, then we'll need a better code sample, to see where is the problem. And the CSS for the footer works without the #. - that's because you have element "footer" that is wrapped up with a div, with id=footer

Comment: As stated in my reply to Akber Iqbal, this isn't a code sample. These are the full, non-shortened .html and .css files. Are you saying that it should work like this and that you do not see a mistake? In that case our purescript worker may have done a mistake on his part.

Comment: I've tried couple of things, take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/52rc1tjk/28/, is this helping?

Comment: Yes, this does work. Except it leaves *too much* space between the last message and the footer now. Still way better than writing "through the footer". Now I'd just need to adjust some spacing numbers, but the solution of Brent Stees already works for me. EDIT: Turning `height: 70vh;` into `height: 90vh;` makes it look fine and do what I want. The 70% in my original code was only a wildcard to see if it works at all.

Comment: I added some more text to your example to visualize the result better. This is the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu9zkqyx/

Comment: try to add css
`  display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse; 
` to the #scroll, worked for me